# laravel 4 auth::attempt password in plaintext

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How do you tell the `laravel auth::attempt` that the password field is stored in plaintext instead of it assuming that it is hashed?

With-in the guard.php

```
public function attempt(array $credentials = array(), $remember = false, $login = true)
{
    $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember, $login);

    $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

    // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
    // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
    // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
    if ($user instanceof UserInterface)
    {
        if ($this->provider->validateCredentials($user, $credentials))
        {
            if ($login) $this->login($user, $remember);

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

or better yet I'll just have 2 columns, one as the plaintext and other as password_secured.

If I try the latter, how do I tell attempt that the password column name is `password_secured.`

Cuz I tried this, and got an error `Undefined index: password`.

```
    $user = array(
        'user_id'           => Input::get('username'),
        'password_secured'  => Input::get('password'),
        'checklogin'        => 0,
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($user)) {
        return 'login success';
    }
```

---

The thing is I'm porting the application, not building from scratch, and I really need the passwords to be stored in plaintext because another application is using the DB (and it is live) and is coded to read the passwords in plaintext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Consider running a script to hash all your passwords**: Storing in plaintext should **never** be mandated or even considered (even if you inherit the system), as those passwords are immediately lost the moment your database contents are leaked. Hacks happen. Imagine the lawsuits if your customers find out you were not dealing with their data according to standards....

Now, assuming you want to not heed this warning, the way to do it is pretty hackish but works. `Guard`, as seen from **the source** (look for `__construct`), is given an object that implements `UserProviderInterface`.

You have a bunch of suitable objects. Pick the one you want, and extend it. We'll have a bit of fun with the `DatabaseUserProvider`, though this extension method is convenient and doable with all of them.

The method we are going to extend is `public function validateCredentials(UserInterface $user, array $credentials)`. As follows:

```
namespace Illuminate\Auth;
class MyUserInterface extends DatabaseUserProvider {
    public function validateCredentials(UserInterface $user, array $credentials) {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];
        return ($plain === $user->getAuthPassword());
    }
}
```

As `MyUserInterface` extends `DatabaseUserProvider` which itself provides `UserProviderInterface`, `MyUserInterface` is now dependency-injectable in `Guard` as a provider. We've done half of the work. The next step is to actually tell Guard to load your thing. I am not familiar with the way Laravel4 loads `Guard` implementations, but somewhere down the config somewhere, you'll be able to set `MyUserInterface` as the Guard interface of choice. I cannot be more specific than this.

By the way, the class needs to be at the same location as other interface implementations for `Auth`.

Comment: Thanks. Got it all setup but I'm still looking for the load implementation. I can't hash all password because another APP that uses the same database is reading it in plaintext and I cannot modify that app nor do I have access to it. I'm just doing the web side. The app is some c++ executable.

Comment: I found it at this line of Guard.php `if ($user instanceof MyUserInterface)`

Comment: OH. Thats wierd its still failing to login.

Comment: Because I'm using Eloquent. I tried editing the EloquentUserProvider.php directly with `($plain === $user->getAuthPassword())` return. But still my login is failing.

Comment: to confirm that it is really the correct function I'm extending i returned 1, and all logins we're successful. I returned 0, all logins we're failed. then i `return ($plain === $user->getAuthPassword());` it still fails.

Comment: @user2415940: No problem, and sorry about the lack of comments - I was out for lunch. For the C++ application... kindly slap the developer(s) for me? Your DB is a pretty juicy target.